# I want to sort the scores but it does work for the value that I entered

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

i want to sort the score when it add to the listbox after game is finished. But the score which added doesn't sort and it sort next time I open the form. I want the score of test sort in order in listbox. But what I got is the score of test is sorted, and it will be sorted next time I open the form.

```
  **public partial class frmScores : Form  
    {  
        string binPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\scores.txt";  
        List<Scores> scores = new List<Scores>();  
        public frmScores()  
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }
       
        public frmScores (string playerName, string playerScore)
        {
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                lblPlayerName.Text = playerName;
                lblPlayerScore.Text = playerScore;
                var reader = new StreamReader(binPath);
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var value = line.Split(',');
                    scores.Add(new Scores(value[0], Int32.Parse(value[1])));
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        } 
        //add scores and name to listboxs 
        public void DisplayScores()
        {
            foreach (Scores s in scores)
            {
                listBoxName.Items.Add(s.Name);
                listBoxScore.Items.Add(s.Score);
            }
        }
        public void SortScores()
        {
            scores = scores.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).Take(10).ToList();
        }
        public void SaveScores()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Scores score in scores)
            {
                builder.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}{2}", score.Name, score.Score, Environment.NewLine));
            }
            File.WriteAllText(binPath, builder.ToString());
        }
        
        private void frmScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int lowest_score = scores[(scores.Count - 1)].Score;
            //show message when the score of player is in top five
            if (int.Parse(lblPlayerScore.Text) > lowest_score)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "CONGRATULATION!! THE TOP TEN!";
                scores.Add(new Scores(lblPlayerName.Text, int.Parse(lblPlayerScore.Text)));
            }
            //show different message when the score is not in top five
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "you could not make the top five...\n\nhope you can make it next time!";
            }
            DisplayScores();
            SortScores();
            SaveScores();
        }**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCHg1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztOHq.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but as text direclty into the question. Furthermor be more specific on what you expect and what you get instead, as well as your data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.